# How to discover the passwords for the Sonic Generations secret trophy room?

Tags: sonic-generations

There is a secret trophy room in Sonic Generations.

> Hold down Select or Back button while inside the Collection Room.

Once inside the trophy room, trophies are unlocked by inputting 6-digit codes.

How can players discover such codes by their own?

I'm not interested in a [list of the codes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOQ4A1Pff0o). I know I can search the web and find such list, but doing so spoils all the fun. What I want to know is how can I discover such codes by myself. Does the game give some hints about the codes? Did SEGA release hints somewhere outside the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, from the looks of it, these are not unlocked in the game. Rather, as [The Sonic Stadium blog](http://www.sonicstadium.org/2011/12/sonic-generations-statue-room-codes/) states (warning some codes are listed, avert your eyes):

> According to Hogfather on the SSMB, the codes are printed on particular merchandise tags e.g. on T-Shirts and pants tags.

Also:

> If you haven’t already scoured the internet to get the hacked codes (because that’s cheating, isn’t it?), then don’t worry, because the [Japanese Generations site](http://sonic.sega.jp/SonicGenerations/figure/index.html) has begun to give out some of these codes!

Looks like these codes are rewards for buying merchandise (or looking them up online).

Also, as a update, it looks like the [official SEGA blog is also releasing these codes](http://blogs.sega.com/2012/02/15/find-hidden-statues-in-sonic-generations/).